# Stability of transport maps implies continuity

Tags: continuity, optimal-transport

In Villani's  Optimal transport boo, it states the stability of transport maps:

[image]

I have also read somewhere that this implies continuity. Intuitively, that makes sense to me, since as much as I remember, stability means there is not much change in the output (the transport plan) when you change the input (in this case the measures).

How does one formally see that the stability of a transport map between two measures implies continuity?